# Flask config.from_object ignored by WSGI server

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to set the environmental variables with the `config.from_object` method. I set the variables for development, but the WSGI server ignore them and run in production mode.
When I print the `app.config` dictionary, the variables I set are in the output, but the application server run with default configurations. I can't figure out where is the mistake...

My `config.py`:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
load_dotenv(os.path.join(basedir, ".env"), verbose=True)


class BaseConfig:
    """Base configs"""

    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
    STATIC_FOLDER = "static"
    TEMPLATE_FOLDER = "templates"
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False


class ProdConfig(BaseConfig):
    """Production configs"""

    FLASK_ENV = "production"
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv("PROD_DATABASE_URI")


class DevConfig(BaseConfig):
    """Development configs"""

    FLASK_ENV = "development"
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv("DEV_DATABASE_URI")
```

My `app.py`:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from pprint import pprint


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object("config.DevConfig")
    pprint(app.config)

    return app
```

The output when I run the app:

```
FLASK_APP=stock/app flask run --host=0.0.0.0
 * Serving Flask app "stock/app"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
{'APPLICATION_ROOT': '/',
 'DEBUG': True,
 'ENV': 'production',
 'EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING': False,
 'FLASK_ENV': 'development',
 'JSONIFY_MIMETYPE': 'application/json',
 'JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR': False,
 'JSON_AS_ASCII': True,
 'JSON_SORT_KEYS': True,
 'MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH': None,
 'MAX_COOKIE_SIZE': 4093,
 'PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=31),
 'PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME': 'http',
 'PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION': None,
 'PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS': None,
 'SECRET_KEY': '\\xc9...\\xaa',
 'SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT': datetime.timedelta(seconds=43200),
 'SERVER_NAME': None,
 'SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN': None,
 'SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY': True,
 'SESSION_COOKIE_NAME': 'session',
 'SESSION_COOKIE_PATH': None,
 'SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE': None,
 'SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE': False,
 'SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST': True,
 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': 'postgresql://...:...@localhost:5432/...',
 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS': False,
 'STATIC_FOLDER': 'static',
 'TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD': None,
 'TEMPLATE_FOLDER': 'templates',
 'TESTING': True,
 'TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS': None,
 'TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS': False,
 'USE_X_SENDFILE': False}
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Edit:

I also set the `ENV` variable, setting it to `development`, but this didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: what config are you setting here - `load_dotenv(os.path.join(basedir, ".env"), verbose=True)
` and how are you starting your app?

Comment: `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` and `SECRET_KEY`

Comment: These variables are in `.env`. `FLASK_ENV` and `DEBUG` are in `config.py`. I'm starting my app with `FLASK_APP=stock/app flask run --host=0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
import config
```

then change

```
app.config.from_object("config.DevConfig")
```

to

```
app.config.from_object(config.DevConfig)
```

Comment: Hi Dave, I'm having the same output here. The variables are setting, but the server is running in production mode...

Comment: When you say "the variables are setting," do you mean that `print(app.config)` shows DevConfig, but when you run in production you're getting ProdConfig?

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean. The values I assign in `config.py` are in the `config` dictionary, but when I run the server it doesn't run in development and debug mode as I expected.